# Optional JOI object if certain value is selected

Tags: reactjs, validation, joi

How would I make an optional/required object based on another value?

I would like `extra` to be required if `dessert` is equal to `Cheese`. If it's set to cake `extra` should not be present.

```
{
  dessert: Joi.string().valid('Cake', 'Cheese').required(),
  extra: Joi.object({
    grapes: Joi.string(),
    wine: Joi.string(),
  })
}
```